# How to Record Phone call

Tags: blackberry-10

Hi I am new to Blackberry 10 platform and I am developing an application to record phone calls  with Blackberry 10 devices. For this application I would like to know if there is possible to create services for listening to phone call? And how can i record a phone call with blackbery 10 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible right now.